# PyInstaller cannot find pyqt4 plugin directories

Tags: pyqt, pyinstaller

I have a PyQt application that I am trying to compile into one exe using PyInstaller 3.1. It does compile into an exe, however, the GUI doesn't show up upon launch (clicking the exe). One of the compilation message is:

> ImportError: No module named site 5576 ERROR: Cannot find PyQt4 plugin
>   directories 5576 WARNING: Hidden import 'PyQT4._qt' not found
>   (probably old hook)

I think this is why the UI wouldn't show up. I've already add all of the paths that has PyQt4 in the pathex attribute for the Analysis object to no avail. Below is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main32.py'],
             pathex=['C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4','./src'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
             win_private_assemblies=None,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='MyExe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
```

Any ideas what's next to try?

Comment: Is `site` the package written by you or it's library dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and I did solve by doing this:

1. Uninstalling PyQt4(*"pip uninstall PyQt4"* on CMD);
2. Deleting the "PyQt4" folder at *"...PythonX\Lib\site-packages\"*;
3. Downloading the ".whl" package from this site: [Python Expansion Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4), **YOU NEED TO DOWNLOAD THE RIGHT WHL**, look the name of the file, since Im using the Python3.5, the file *"PyQt4‑4.11.4‑**cp35**‑none‑win32.whl"* worked for me!
4. Installing again, opening the CMD at the file's location and typing:
   *"pip install PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp35‑none‑win32.whl"*. Of course you'll type your file's name.

> Note: Only by uninstalling, I could compile my script. But if you are really using PyQt4 code, you gonna need to install it again.
>   Please, thumbs up if it worked for you too! ;)